# AndEngineを使ったAndroidアプリにAdMob広告を表示したい

Tags: android, admob

「AndEngineでつくる Android 2Dゲーム」という本を購入し、勉強をしていました。

最後の最後、本の情報が古いからでしょうか、本の通りにやっても広告の表示ができなくて困ってしまいました。

本の通りと言っても、AdMob自体は最新のものです。エラーも起きていません。
が、どうしてもloadAd();のところで強制終了です。

みなさんどのようにしてAdMob広告を表示してますか？ソースを教えていただきたいです。

思い切った、図々しい質問で申し訳ありません。

一つではないでしょうけども、ズバリ正解のある質問だと思いましたので、「このようなソースですがどこが悪いのでしょう」などと質問するより、「こうすればできる！」というのを提示していただいた方が、こちらの知識不足で情報を十分に伝えることができない、などの事態が避けられると思いましたので、このような形にさせていただきました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @user7481 ロールバックを実行しました。どうしても、という場合にはご質問のクローズ処理をお勧めします。

Answer (score 1):

「AndEngineでつくる Android 2Dゲーム」という本を持っていないので、一般的なAdMobの設置方法で。

1 GooglePlayServicesをdependenciesに追加する

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
```

2 AndroidManifest.xmlのの子に次のエントリーを追加する

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

３ ActivityのonCreate()あたりで、AdViewインスタンスを生成しViewに追加

```
mAdView = new AdView(this);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(Constants.ADMOB_ID);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("テストデバイス用のID")
        .build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

FrameLayout adLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_ad);
adLayout.addView(mAdView);
```

4 onResume() / onPause() / onDestroy()でそれぞれメソッドを呼ぶ

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAdView.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mAdView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mAdView.destroy();
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
AndEngineはSceneというビューを使って、一つのActivityの中で複数のゲーム画面を描写するという独自の方法を使っているものです。
なので一般的な設置方法では使うことができず困っているのが現状です。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: AndEngineの使い方をちょっと読んできました。
- AndroidのレイアウトXMLを利用する(その中にAndEngine提供のViewを配置する)
- Activityは通常のアプリと同様に操作可能

なので、使うことができない　と判断される根拠がないと思うのですがどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

私も勉強中です。同様に表示されなくて悩んでいましたが、以下でなんとかできました。

具体的には、MainActivity内にonCreateメソッドを追記してください。
あの本だとonCreateSceneに書くように指定してあるんですよね。

```
public class MainActivity extends MultiSceneActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("xxxxxxxx")
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

すでに解決済みでしょうか。